# How to do multiprocessing in async gRPC server in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, subprocess, grpc

I want to combine multiprocessing and asyncio.
I setup an async gRPC server in python and want to do multiprocessing.

More specifically: When the server receives a Message from a client I want to run a compute heavy function in another process, retrieve the result and send it back over the gRPC channel. I tried using `anyio` without much success (nothing get's returned, can't even say for sure if the subprocess is being created)

Here is some skeleton code to replicate my experiments.

##### Protofile `test.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

service Test {
   rpc test_stream(stream TestMessage) returns (stream TestMessage) {}
}

message TestMessage {
   string txt = 1;
}
```

##### Python server code

```py
import time
import asyncio
import grpc
from test_pb2_grpc import TestServicer, add_TestServicer_to_server
from test_pb2 import TestMessage
from anyio import to_process
import os

def cpu_intensive_function(message):
    time.sleep(1)
    data = message.txt
    # To show the function is running in a different process
    output = f"from PID {os.getpid()}: {data[::-1]}"
    return output

class NewTestServicer(TestServicer):
    async def test_stream(self, request_iterator, context):
        async for client_message in request_iterator:
            print(f"Incoming client message: {client_message.txt}")
            response = await to_process.run_sync(cpu_intensive_function, client_message)
            yield TestMessage(txt=response)

async def serve():
    server = grpc.aio.server()
    add_TestServicer_to_server(NewTestServicer(), server)
    listen_addr = "[::]:50051"
    server.add_insecure_port(listen_addr)
    await server.start()
    print(f"Starting server on {listen_addr}")
    await server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(serve())
```

##### Python client code

```py
import grpc
import asyncio
from test_pb2_grpc import TestStub
from test_pb2 import TestMessage

messages = [
    "Hello",
    "world",
    "from",
    "client",
]

async def generate_messages():
    for message in messages:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        yield TestMessage(txt=message)

async def main():
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel("localhost:50051") as channel:
        client = TestStub(channel)
        responses = client.test_stream(generate_messages())
        async for response in responses:
            print(f"Response from server: {response.txt}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

<s>### What should happen:
The client should print:</s>

```bash
olleH
dlrow
```

#### What actually happens:

Nothing. The client doesn't receive anything

The [documentation for `anyio`](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/subprocesses.html#running-functions-in-worker-processes) shows the main async function should be started with `anyio.run`, I haven't figured out how to combine that with `asyncio`.

## EDIT:

The posted code above actually works 100%. Of course I didn't have my own code exactly as the above and while typing out the problem it occurred to me to test this first and it works. The `cpu_intensive–function` is run in a different process every time and connecting multiple clients works without any deadlocks.

This is what the console looks like, when running the client:

```bash
Response from server: from PID 1689552: olleH
Response from server: from PID 1688876: dlrow
Response from server: from PID 1689552: morf
Response from server: from PID 1688876: tneilc
```